# selenium - Unsupported command dragAndDrop with switch to ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, format, selenium-ide

I have a nice test suite in the selenium IDE using the HTML format.

I wish to change that to ruby.
I try the format change to ruby/rspec but I get

```
# ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [dragAndDrop | xpath=
(//div[@id='external-events']/div[contains(text(),'My Event 1')]) | 300,150]]
```

Any way to get around this and avoid the error? Do other Ruby formats get around this?

I also dried dragdrop but got the same error.

Comment: Are you exporting your test cases into Ruby you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the IDE functions are unable to be converted directly into the language of your choice. DragAndDrop is one of them, I don't think it's implemented for any of the exports.

You'll have to use the `ActionBuilder`:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html